# Java loading library windows 7 64bit

Tags: java, dll, load, 32bit-64bit

I have a java webstart program, it runs on xp, osx, vista, and windows 7.
I just tried to run it on windows 7 64bit and it is having a problem loading a library.
On this win7x64 machine I have the 64bit jdk/jre and the library it is not loading is swt-win32.dll. Yeah it's 32bit, but I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-win32-3325 or swt-win32 in swt.library.path, java.libary.path or the jar file...
```

I have tried putting the dll on the java.library.path (physically copying it to the folder) and still get the exact same error. So am I getting this error because it's a 32bit dll or because it actually just can't find it? can the 64bit jdk/jre load/use 32bit dll's or do I need to either find the 64bit version of the dll or run the 32bit jdk/jre?

Answer (score 3):

You have the answer already. 64-bit DLL's require the 64-bit JDK and 32-bit DLL's require the 32-bit JDK.

Comment: I've found the JDK errors messages regarding native libraries aren't always the most intuitive. I'd also suggest testing outside of webstart.

Comment: @basszero This testing was outside of webstart :/

Answer (score 0):

swt-win32.dll is actually a SWT UI framework(eclipse) dll. Try putting it in a directory which is in your system path.

If that doesn't work, then your next best bet would be to get the SWT binaries for 64 bit windows [here](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.4-200806172000/index.php#SWT). I think it works for windows Vista 64. There is no mention of windows 7 but it "should" work.